Запись екрана встроеными средствами windows 11
Редко обращаюсь на stack overflow за помощью, но винда достала создавать проблемы на ровном месте, я не знаю как решить свою проблему.
Winsows 11 домашняя 23H2
Когда я нажимал клавишу print screen у меня появлялось такое окно в котором я мог выбрать либо запись экрана либо скриншот

После какого то момента при нажатии на эту клавишу начало появляться это окно

Я не смог найти сочитание клавиш, открывавших первое окно, есть только разные записи с помощью xbox модуля. Смог только открыть это окно с помощью приложения ножниц, но так активировать запись экрана весьма неудобно.
Не знаю что изменило работу винды, единственное что, недавно я сбросил параметры "приложениий по умолчанию", может это повлияло.
Я не уверен что print screen открывал нужное мне окно, но точно существовало сочетание клавиш, делавшее это.
Прошу подсказать какое сочетание клавиш мне нужно нажимать, либо как настроить открытие первого окна при нажатии print screen.
Спасибо

В настройках "Ножниц" покопайтесь, там будет и про назначение клавиш. А вообще, сочитание клавиш всегда Win+Shift+S.

Windows 11 24H2. Работает и PrtScr, и Win+Shift+S. Но это зависит от текущего контекста. Должно быть сверху нечто, что может быть записано. Например, пока я печатаю в этом окне PrtScr работает, но если я закрою всё и запущу программу, в которой одни кнопки в одном окне, PrtScr выключится, а Win+Shift+S по-прежнему будет работать.

А теперь собственно по делу. В настройках Windows 11 есть об этом: Специальные возможности - Клавиатура.

@EvgeniyZ - Поискал в Ножницах, там только настройки сохранения скринов и записей, вспомогательные какие то настройки, и есть конечно ссылка на главные параметры Windows где можно просто вкл/выкл фукнкционал клавиши PrtScr. Win+Shift+S открывает второе окно и дублирует PrtScr,

@Fox Fox - Понял логику контекста, попробовал в разных приложениях, но даже в firefox где две недели назад запускал запись, что PrtScr, что Win+Shift+S вызывает функционал второго окна, то есть только скриншота. В Специальные возможности - Клавиатура порылся, ничего не нашел кроме вкл/выкл фукнкционал клавиши PrtScr, если у вас есть подобные настройки, скиньте пожалуйста скриншот, я хоть буду примерно понимать от чего мне отталкиваться.

@EvgeniyZ.....Fox Fox    - Благодарю, товарищи за новый приток сил поискать решение, я его наконец нашел.

В Windows 11 ещё и Ctrl+PrtScr работает. Безо всяких окон приложений копирует полное содержимое экрана в буфер.

Попробуйте нажать сочетание горячих клавиш Win + SHIFT + R (у вас должно вызвать запись области экрана, которая должна появится как при открытом окне (чего-то), так и на рабочем столе, а потом нажмите PrtSc.
НО! я просмотрел приложения по-умолчанию (поскольку вы сказали что сбросили их) и смог спроецировать такую самую проблему. У вас может быть выбрана другая утилита для скринов и записи. Зайдите в "Приложения по умолчанию" и выберите "Ножницы" и проверьте, чтобы у вас там были ножницы.

Но вы уже решили проблему)

Увидел ваш ответ только после того как записал ответ. Интересная у вас логика поиска решения, спасибо за иной способ, теперь я знаю какой конкретно параметр отвечает за хоткей скрина и записи. Благодарю вас

Да (я уже понял) Спасибо вам тоже и хорошей ночи)

Решение следующее: Вероятно, в приложении Ножницы произошел сбой, и нам нужно сбросить приложение.
Для этого заходим в Параметры Windows > Приложения > Установленные Приложения > > ищем в поиске Ножницы, нажимаем три точки, и выбираем дополнительные параметры > ищем в самом низу списка "Сброс". После этого у меня на клавиши PrtScr / Win+Shift+S / Win+Shift+R открывается окно где я могу выбрать либо скриншот либо запись экрана, и это меня полностью устраивает.
Вот и все, всем Спасибо за помощь ^3^
